# Concatenates the values of string expressions in azure synapse serverless pool

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse, azure-sql-server

I would like to write a query in serverless pool for concatenation of string values from multiple rows into single row with comma separated values. I  am getting below error when I use COALESE function which I am unable to fix **"Queries referencing variables are not supported in distributed processing mode"**

Input rows :
A
B
C
A
B
Output row (Looking for distinct values only while creating a list like below)
A,B,C

Answer (score 0):

You can use [STRING_AGG()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function to concatenate values from multiple rows to a single row with comma-separated.

Get distinct values of a column and apply STRING_AGG on the results as below.

```
select STRING_AGG(col1, ',') output_col1 from (select distinct col1 from #tb1) a
```

[image]

Comment: In the temp table, I'm trying to insert distinct values from the select query and it is getting the same error 

INSERT INTO #tb1 (col) 
SELECT DISTINCT test_col
FROM mytable

Comment: In short, I am looking for a query on mytable that returns multiple rows, and then insert those into #tb1 in a single loop.